# Double hash before parameter in function call

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I see this line in C:

```
#define log(format, args...) snprintf(buffer + strlen(buffer), 1023 - strlen(buffer), format, ##args);
```

What does the double pound / hash mean before the last param in `snprintf()`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In standard C, the "`##`" is for concatenating tokens together within a macro. Here, this macro is not in standard C, but in "Gnu C", the dialect implemented by [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). The "`##`" is used to remove the comma if the extra arguments (in `args`) turn out to be empty. See [the GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Variadic-Macros.html).

Comment: What a shame that GCC would reuse a defined operator rather than coming up with something unique.

Comment: @Mark: to their defence, the GCC people defined their syntax for macros with a variable number of arguments before there was any such thing in standard C. And both syntaxes can coexist.

Answer (score 2):

That's the ["token-pasting"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_concatenation) [preprocessor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09dwwt6y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) [operator](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html), and I don't think that macro uses it correctly.

Comment: Token concatenation(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_concatenation) is also an operator but Variadic-Macros(https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Variadic-Macros.html) is specific to GCC. See Mark Ransom's comment to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a gcc extension (so is `args...`, the C99 version is to use `...` and `__VA_ARGS__`) to remove the final comma if the variable argument list `args` is empty.